# BotomSheetDialog crashes while inflating: ClassCastException CoordinatorLayout cannot be cast to FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-design-library

I have been facing a crash when I call `BottomSheetDialog`. This crash started suddenly on a code which has been working fine, and I am certain that I have not updated any support library or the design library.

Seems like the layout inflated for `BottomSheetDialog` is changed from what there was previously. The top level view has been changed from `FrameLayout` to `CoordinatorLayout`.

The strangest thing though is that the same library version is being used in another project and it works fine.
Has anyone else faced this issue?

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout
    at com.doctor247.patient.app.view.helper.ui.CustomBottomSheetDialog.wrapInBottomSheet(CustomBottomSheetDialog.java:97)
    at com.doctor247.patient.app.view.helper.ui.CustomBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(CustomBottomSheetDialog.java:67)
    at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onActivityCreated(DialogFragment.java:411)
    ...
```

UploadDocumentsFragment.java

```
public class UploadShareDocumentsFragment extends AppCompatDialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

LinearLayout cameraContainer, galleryContainer, documentsContainer, uploadsContainer;
TextView close;

ArrayList<Document> sharedUserDocuments;
ArrayList<Document> patientDocuments;

IUploadChooserListener uploadChooserListener;

public UploadShareDocumentsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (getActivity() instanceof HomeActivity) {
        // then inflate without document sharing
    } else {

    }
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_upload_documents, container, false);

    sharedUserDocuments = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList(Constant.SHARED_DOCUMENTS);
    patientDocuments = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList(Constant.PATIENT_DOCUMENTS);

    cameraContainer = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.cameraContainer);
    galleryContainer = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.galleryContainer);
    documentsContainer = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.documentsContainer);
    uploadsContainer = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.uploadsContainer);

    if (getActivity() instanceof HomeActivity)
        uploadsContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    close = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.close);
    close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            UploadShareDocumentsFragment.this.dismiss();
        }
    });

    cameraContainer.setOnClickListener(this);
    galleryContainer.setOnClickListener(this);
    documentsContainer.setOnClickListener(this);
    uploadsContainer.setOnClickListener(this);

    return v;
}

public void setUploadChooserListener(IUploadChooserListener uploadChooserListener) {
    this.uploadChooserListener = uploadChooserListener;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return new UploadDocumentFragment.BottomSheetDialog(getActivity(), getTheme());
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.cameraContainer) {

        uploadChooserListener.onCameraClicked();

    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.galleryContainer) {

        uploadChooserListener.onGalleryClicked();

    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.documentsContainer) {

        uploadChooserListener.onDocumentClicked();

    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.uploadsContainer) {
        // start activity for result to uploaded Documents activity and get the selected document
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), UploadedDocumentsListActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(PATIENT, ((DoctorDetailsActivity) getActivity()).patient);
        intent.putExtra(DOCTOR, ((DoctorDetailsActivity) getActivity()).doctor);
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Constant.SHARED_DOCUMENTS, sharedUserDocuments);
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Constant.PATIENT_DOCUMENTS, patientDocuments);
        //intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(DOCUMENTS, ((DoctorDetailsActivity)getActivity()).getDocuments());
        getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, SHARE_FILE);
        // intent.putExtra(Constant.)
    }
    this.dismiss();
}

    static class BottomSheetDialog extends android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialog {
        public BottomSheetDialog(@NonNull Context context, @StyleRes int theme) {
            super(context, theme);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            int width = getContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.bottom_sheet_width);
            //noinspection ConstantConditions
            getWindow().setLayout(
                width > 0 ? width : ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        }
    }
}
```

fragment_upload_documents.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.doctor247.patient.app.view.fragment.dialog.UploadShareDocumentsFragment">

<com.doctor247.patient.app.view.helper.CustomFontTextView
    style="@style/TextAppearance.Info"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/upload_document"
    app:fontName="bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cameraContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/camera" />

        <com.doctor247.patient.app.view.helper.CustomFontTextView
            style="@style/TextAppearance.Info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/camera"
            app:fontName="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/galleryContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/gallery" />

        <com.doctor247.patient.app.view.helper.CustomFontTextView
            style="@style/TextAppearance.Info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/gallery"
            app:fontName="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/documentsContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_pdf" />

        <com.doctor247.patient.app.view.helper.CustomFontTextView
            style="@style/TextAppearance.Info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/pdf"
            app:fontName="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/uploadsContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/document" />

        <com.doctor247.patient.app.view.helper.CustomFontTextView
            style="@style/TextAppearance.Info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/uploads"
            app:fontName="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<com.doctor247.patient.app.view.helper.CustomFontTextView
    android:id="@+id/close"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.Prefix"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="@string/close"
    app:fontName="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you put some code

Comment: Make sure DialogFragment layout file contains CoordinatorLayout as Parent Layout